# Деплой Telegram бота на Heroku Java

Tags: java, telegram-bot, maven, heroku

Не работает бот при деплое на Heroku. Сам деплой проходит успешно, но бот не отвечает на команды. Есть подозрение что неправильно заполняю pom.xml. Что делать? Бот работает на LongPoll. Библиотека - https://github.com/rubenlagus/TelegramBots
В коде классы Main и Bot
В Main происходит регистрация бота, логика самого бота описана в Bot
Файл Proclife

```
worker: sh target/bin/workerBot
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>TGBotShedule</groupId>
    <artifactId>ru.tlgrm.bot.shedule</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.telegram</groupId>
            <artifactId>telegrambots</artifactId>
            <version>4.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains</groupId>
            <artifactId>annotations</artifactId>
            <version>RELEASE</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>appassembler-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <assembleDirectory>target</assembleDirectory>
                    <programs>
                        <program>
                            <mainClass>Main</mainClass>
                            <name>workerBot</name>
                        </program>
                    </programs>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>assemble</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: простите, почему вы решили, что ошибка в самом pom.xml?

Comment: у меня была аналогичная проблема: запустил бота локально, только на одного юзера отвечал. Я остановил бота в телеге, затем запустил заново. Попробуйте, может это поможет

Comment: На локалке работает всё прекрасно, отвечает на запросы нескольких пользователей. Мне кажется что у ошибка может быть именно при сборке файла

Comment: К тому же я не могу определиться, правильно ли я описал `<mainClass>Main</mainClass>`

Comment: @cinilya1712 я бы порекомендовал бы выставить на VPS сервере бота. Порекомендовал бы Вам попробовать [DigitalOcean](https://Digitalocean.com)

Comment: Я пытался запустить своего бота на Heroku, но VPS стал для меня лучшим вариантом решения